# What is an idiomatic way to implement double loop over a vector in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I am new to Clojure and it's hard for me to idiomatically implement basic manipulations with data structures.

What would be an idiomatic way to implement the following code in Clojure?

```
l = [...]
for i in range(len(l)):
  for j in range(i + 1, len(l)):
    print l[i], l[j]
```

Comment: As already mentioned `doseq` is a way. But when you want to manipulate data, then probably `map` or `for` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the simplest (but not the most FP-ish) is almost identical to your example:

```
(let [v [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
  (doseq [i (range (count v))
          j (range (inc i) (count v))]
    (println (v i) (v j))))
```

and here is more functional variant to generate all these pairs (it isn't based on length or indices, but rather on the tail iteration):

```
(let [v [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
  (mapcat #(map (partial vector (first %)) (rest %))
          (take-while not-empty (iterate rest v))))
```

output:

```
 ([1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [1 6] [1 7] [2 3] [2 4] 
  [2 5] [2 6] [2 7] [3 4] [3 5] [3 6] [3 7] [4 5] 
  [4 6] [4 7] [5 6] [5 7] [6 7])
```

then just use these pairs in `doseq` for any side effect:

```
(let [v [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
      pairs (fn [items-seq]
              (mapcat #(map (partial vector (first %)) (rest %))
                      (take-while not-empty (iterate rest items-seq))))]
  (doseq [[i1 i2] (pairs v)] (println i1 i2)))
```

update: following @dg123's answer. it is nice, but you can make it even better, using `doseq`'s and `for`'s features like destructuring and guards:

```
(let [v [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]]
  (doseq [[x & xs] (iterate rest v)
          :while xs
          y xs]
    (println "x:" x "y:" y)))
```

you iterate through the tails of a collection, but remember, that `iterate` produces an infinite coll:

```
user> (take 10 (iterate rest [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]))
([1 2 3 4 5 6 7] (2 3 4 5 6 7) (3 4 5 6 7) 
 (4 5 6 7) (5 6 7) (6 7) (7) () () ())
```

so you have to limit it somehow to include just not empty collections.
the destructuring form `[x & xs]` splits the argument to a first param and the sequence of the rest params:

```
user> (let [[x & xs] [1 2 3 4 5 6]]
        (println x xs))
1 (2 3 4 5 6)
nil
```

and when the binded collection is empty, or have a single element, the `xs` would be `nil`:

```
user> (let [[x & xs] [1]]
        (println x xs))
1 nil
nil
```

so you just make use of this feature, using `:while` guard in a list comprehension.

in the end you just construct pairs (or do some side effect in this case) for `x` and every item in `xs`

Comment: You should replace the `(v i)` with `(nth v i)` (when `v` is not a vector).

Answer (score 3):

How about using `map vector` and `iterate`:

```
user=> (def l [1 2 3 4 5])
#'user/l
user=> (map vector l (iterate rest (drop 1 l)))
([1 (2 3 4 5)] [2 (3 4 5)] [3 (4 5)] [4 (5)] [5 ()])
```

which produces a lazy sequence of the value of each `i` index followed by all of its `j`s.

You can then iterate over all of the pairs of values you need using `for` like so:

```
user=> (for [[i js] (map vector l (iterate rest (drop 1 l))) 
             j js] 
         [i j])
([1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [1 5] [2 3] [2 4] [2 5] [3 4] [3 5] [4 5])
```

Use `doseq` if you would like to perform IO instead of producing a lazy sequence:

```
user=> (doseq [[i js] (map vector l (iterate rest (drop 1 l))) 
               j js] 
         (println (str "i: " i " j: " j)))
i: 1 j: 2
i: 1 j: 3
i: 1 j: 4
i: 1 j: 5
i: 2 j: 3
i: 2 j: 4
i: 2 j: 5
i: 3 j: 4
i: 3 j: 5
i: 4 j: 5
nil
```